# App installed from Google Play doesn't appear in menu after installation

Tags: android, installation, google-play

I have a problem. I have registered in Google Play and uploaded my app.
But after installation, the app doesn't open and the app isn't in the menu.

So what should I do to make it appear?

Comment: What is the question here? By convention (and grammar rules) questions end with the question mark.

Comment: Hello @user1468102 what process u follow for uploading the app in Google app?????